# Store / Save a @State Array (UserDefaults)

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

```
@State var cardData: [Card] = [
        Card(number: 1 ,start: "05.06.2020", end: "15.06.2020", days: 10, success: true)
    ]
```

I have cardData, and the user can add more Elements to this array. But I want that it will be saved. Like UserDefaults. Is it possible to Store this (cardData) to UserDefaults?
If not, how can I save it permanent?
Thank you so much!

Comment: UserDefaults is not for this purpose, use CoreData.

Comment: is it only possible with CoreData?

Comment: Why do you have multiple accounts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537392/after-appending-element-to-array-it-should-show-more-elements/63538922#63538922

Comment: I am on my other computer

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways. on would be adding a `.onChange` modifier to your view (available on Xcode 12, not sure about 11):

```
.onChange(of: cardData) { newValue in
           UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "Your_UserDefaults_Key")
}
```

I noticed you are using a custom type that you've made. in that case you first need to convert all your data to some Type that can be saved to UserDefaults (like string, using codable, see: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-load-and-save-a-struct-in-userdefaults-using-codable)

As someone mentioned, this might not be the best way of saving your data on a persistent storage. If you plan to save a lot of data, and you don't need all that data at all times (for example, most of the times you only need one of those all cards) you should not use UserDefaults, and use `CoreData` instead. Using UserDefaults is not efficient in the case i described, because you have to get all the data from the device's storage everytime (you can't ask to only get the one card you need using UserDefaults, but you can do that using CoreData). And also when saving data to the device's storage, you have to replace the whole old data with some new data (in CoreData you can simply just add one more card. you won't need to replace (all-current-cards) with (all-current-cards + 1-new-card) )

Comment: Okay thank you. So you would recommend me to use CoreData?

Comment: i am not fully aware of your situation. if there are a lot of cards, with no limitations of number, you should definitely use coredata. otherwise i've described when to use coredata and when you can just use userdefaults in the answer. if still you don't know which to use, you should use coredata as it is the safe way.

Comment: How much do you want if you would do that for me?

Comment: I'm afraid i'm going to decline you offer, but i can suggest to read 2 articles by Paul Hudson and Donny Wals. first is to make your coredata model and second one is to use coredata with SwiftUI. i'm not sure if they are enough to get working with coredata, but they will help you at least. making a coredata model: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/38/2/designing-a-core-data-model . using SwiftUI with Coredata: https://www.donnywals.com/fetching-objects-from-core-data-in-a-swiftui-project (this might be a little bit high level, but you'll need to read it at least after you learned coredata)